# Referencing a file in an aws emr script run by script-runner.jar

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

I am creating an amazon emr cluster where one of the steps is a bash script run by `script-runner.jar`:

```
aws emr create cluster ... --steps '[ ... {
 "Args":["s3://bucket/scripts/script.sh"],
 "Type":"CUSTOM_JAR",
 "ActionOnFailure":"TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
 "Jar":"s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar",
}, ... ]'...
```

as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html

`script.sh` needs other files in its commands: think `awk ... -f file`, `sed ... -f file`, `psql ... -f file`, etc.

On my laptop with both `script.sh` and `file`s in my working directory, everything works just fine. However, after I upload everything to `s3://bucket/scripts`, the cluster creation fails with:

```
 file: No such file or directory
 Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I have found the workaround posted below, but I don't like it for the reasons specified. If you have a better solution, please post it, so that I can accept it.

Comment: May I ask how you've solved this? I am looking to add the arguments in the line below to an "aws emr add-steps".  -- -s $SCRIPT -c $CONFIG_FILE_NAME -r $CONFIG_ROOT -l myMetrics

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following work around in `script.sh`:

```
# Download the SQL file to a tmp directory.
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}$(basename $0).XXXXXXXXXXXX")
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/scripts/file ${tmpdir}

# Run my command
xxx -f ${tmpdir}/file

# Clean up
rm -r ${tmpdir}
```

This approach works but:

- Running `script.sh` locally means that I have to upload `file` to s3 first, which makes development harder.
- There are actually a few `files` involved...